# Add card as an external_account to Stripe managed account

Tags: stripe-connect

I'm trying to add a card as a destination to a managed account as per https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_create_card. Request goes like this:

```
HTTP Method                  POST
HTTP URI                     https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts/<acct_id>/external_accounts
HTTP Protocol                HTTP/1.1

HTTP Header                  Accept : application/json
HTTP Header                  Authorization : Basic <auth_value>
HTTP Header                  Stripe-Version : 2016-07-06

HTTP Content                 application/x-www-form-urlencoded
HTTP Body                    external_account[object]=card
HTTP Body                    external_account[cvc]=121
HTTP Body                    external_account[exp_month]=11
HTTP Body                    external_account[exp_year]=2018
HTTP Body                    external_account[number]=4000056655665556
HTTP Body                    external_account[currency]=usd`
```

Server replies with such json:

```
{
  "error" : {
  "type" : "invalid_request_error",
  "message" : "Requests made on behalf of a connected account must use card tokens from Stripe.js, but card details were directly provided.",
  "param" : "external_account"
  }
}
```

what am I missing? We don't use stripe.js, all interaction with Stripe happens on the backend.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution for this? i am facing the same issue and I don't want to use Stripe.js in my project. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DavidHope, I vaguely recall a conversation with their customer support person. He said if interaction with Stripe happens on backend, we were forced to use card tokens because it may be insecure to store and handle card details on backend.

Answer (score -4):

you are using card details and passing it to external_account parameter which only takes the token of the card. To use card details just pass the object, cvc etc parameters directly. don't send these details to external_account paramter

Comment: Could you be more specific about endpoints involved? I thought customers were entities that only can send money, not receive.

Comment: you are using card details and passing it to external_account parameter which only takes the token of the card. To use card details just pass the object, cvc etc parameters directly. don't send these details to external_account paramter

Comment: Something like `curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts/acct_18ei8DDnFIdh8uQ1 \
      -u sk_test_HqgOzbe7IY6jCaJzK1xhZxxt: \
      -d "external_account[object]=card&external_account[cvc]=121&external_account[exp_month]=11&external_account[exp_year]=2018&external_account[number]=4000056655665556&external_account[currency]=usd&external_account[default_for_currency]=true"`? Doesn't work either